# How to find the value of a user created button

Tags: php

At first I created the buttons and therefore I knew the name of the button and was able to use:

```
//function button clicked 
if (isset($_POST['thenameofthebutton'])) {

}
```

I would simply write the name manually in the code  for the button in my function "button clicked".

However now the buttons are created from user data with PHP and SQL.

I create the buttons like this and its working fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chooseCategory";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ' <input type="submit" name="'.$row['Name']
    .'" value="'.$row['Name']
    .'">
    </form>';
}
```

My question is how I can create my function "button clicked" so it works dynamically with the buttons being created from user input instead of me manually creating them in code.

Comment: Please post your full code of creation of form

Comment: @KamleshSolanki that's unnecessary. Chao1920 intends to somehow identify which of the submit buttons was clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create multiple submit inputs, only the one actually clicked is submitted alongside the form, the others are ignored, even if thay have a value.
So you can create multiple submit buttons with the same name and only change their values, like this.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ' <input type="submit" name="submitted-btn" value="'.$row['Name'].'">';
}
```

When the form is submitted, `$_POST['submitted-btn']` will contain the `$row['name']` of the clicked button.
So in your page you can do `if(isset($_POST['submitted-btn']))` to check if the form is being submitted and use `$_POST['submitted-btn']` to get which button was clicked.

Please note that the generated HTML produces a very different `$_POST` when submitted to the server, so you may have to change your code if it relies on the given structure.

Answer (score -1):

Let's create an `input` into the `form` which will hold the clicked button `name` and make sure we set its value when such a button is being clicked:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chooseCategory";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo '<input type="hidden" id="clicked-button">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ' <input type="submit" name="'.$row['Name']
    .'" value="'.$row['Name']
    .'" onclick="document.getElementById(\"clicked-button\").value = this.name;">
    ';
}
echo '</form>';
```

And then you will be able to do this:

```
if ((isset($_POST["clicked-button"])) && (isset($_POST[$_POST["clicked-button"]]))) {
    $clickedButton = $_POST[$_POST["clicked-button"]];
    //the name of the clicked button is stored in $clickedButton
}
```

EDIT

```
<form action="testing.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="clicked-button"> <input type="submit" name="lasor" value="lasor" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="kat" value="kat" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="beta" value="beta" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="versa" value="versa" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="general" value="general" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="testing" value="testing" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="cola" value="cola" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="simba" value="simba" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      <input type="submit" name="michelle" value="michelle" onclick="document.getElementById('clicked-button').value = this.name";>
      </form>
```

Comment: I've been trying to implement your solution but with no luck. Its seems there is some kind of syntax error, maybe a " or ' in the form. I can't seem to find it, I think its around the line with the "document.getElement".

Comment: @Chao1920 sorry about that, did not have the chance to test the code. There was a typo, please test again.

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick respons! However $clickedButton is empty. 

I tried doing a simple echo to see if the "if" statements its true, but it seems not to be?

Comment: @Chao1920 can you create a JSFiddle? I'm sure there is something simple we miss.

Comment: I never tried JSFiddle, I might have to spent a few mins figure it out. It's seems like there is nothing inside: $_POST["clicked-button"]

It's like it does not get any value.  I can see my buttons are have the value's so I know i'm getting my values from the database successfully.

Comment: @Chao1920 I understood the problem, but do not know what causes it. Maybe a typo or something. If you create a JSFiddle then I will be able to find what the problem is.

Comment: Well I feel stupid now, because I can't figure out how to implement PHP and my SQL to JSFiddle. (its all locally at the moment) 

I made one just with my HTML/PHP, but I guess that wont make any sense at all or help you. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5uc3j8zp/

Comment: @Chao1920 no problem, you can just view the page source of the HTML you have generated (right-click on the browser) and paste the relevant part of the code into the JSFiddle.

Comment: thanks. Here it is. 
https://jsfiddle.net/cje5wytp/

Comment: @Chao1920 there was a typo on my part and also, your cycle printed the form closing for every button.

Comment: @Chao1920 in the fiddle I have made the input visible, so you will actually see the changes of its value as you test, but when everything is okay, you will need to change its type back to hidden to not show it unnecessarily.